# Error when trying to insert data into Mysql db through HTML and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

### Am trying to make an entry of username and password into a MySql database through Html via a php file.Here is the html code.

```
<div id="JoinModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
             <!-- Modal Content -->
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Join </h4>
             </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <form action="demo4.php" method="POST">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label><b>Email address:</b></label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control input-sm">
                       </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <label><b>Password:</b></label>
                             <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control input-sm">
                          </div>  
                   <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                             <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="form-control input-sm">
                          </div>   
                             <div class="checkbox">
                                <label style="color:black;">
                                   <input type="checkbox"><small> Remember Me</small>
                                </label>
                             </div>  
                               <button type="submit" id="signIn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Sign In</button>
                               <button type="button" id="cancelModal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </form>             
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

Here is the php code:

```
    <?php  // <-- if you don't open the php tag, your code won't work
    $servername="localhost";
    $dbname="schema1";
    $password="1234";
    $user="root";
    $port ="3306";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$user,$password);



    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed:" .$conn->connect_error);
  }

  echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server!";


    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

     if (!$db_selected){
      die("Cant use db: " .mysql_error());
    }

    echo 'Connected successfully to database';

  // $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST)['email'];
  // echo ( "email is:" .$email) ;

  // $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST)['password'];

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Members (email,password)
            VALUES ('$email', '$password')";

  if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    die('Error!!: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
  else {
    echo "Success:";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

---

When I enter the username and password in the browser i get this error :(it just displays the phpfile back)

Error when trying to insert data into Mysql db through HTML and php

```
connect_error) { die("connection failed:" .$conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server!"; $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname); if (!$db_selected){ die("Cant use db: " .mysql_error()); } echo 'Connected successfully to database'; // $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST)['email']; // echo ( "email is:" .$email) ; // $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_REQUEST)['password']; $email = $_POST['email']; $password = $_POST['password']; $sql = 'INSERT INTO `Members` (`email`,`password`) VALUES (:email, :password)'; if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) { die('Error!!: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); } else { echo "Success:"; } $conn->close(); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: `it just displays the phpfile back`->are you sure php is installed properly. Also which one you are using among  `Xampp/Lamp/Wamp/Mamp` to run your php file?

Comment: make sure your file is .php and no html, also that you have php installed

Comment: please open php tag

Comment: Am using Apache .The php open tag is there.(just hvnt copied it ..by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

the connection is failed because you forgot to write _connect
that's correct

```
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$user,$password);
```

Comment: This is wrong.  There is mysqli procedural style and object oriented style. OP is using the latter

Comment: Lol you didn't check the link properly.  `new mysqli()` is properly valid. Go through the link you sent. Read the comments before adding an answer

Comment: I know mate, my first comment was about the procedural style, but you said you want the OO style so I just posted this link in case you didn't check it out yet. cheers

Comment: Yes I hear you. But that is certainly not the issue with OP's code. The way OP initialized the connection is valid

Answer (score 0):

those error shows that database connection is not established.check that first if still error found check your file is .php or not.

Check by This

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$user,$password, $dbname);
if($conn){
 echo "Connection Success";
}else{
 echo "Connection Failed";
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  There is mysqli procedural style and object oriented style. OP is using the latter